# Find My won't release my computer, asks for an Apple ID that I changed e-mail for

Tags: apple-id, find-my-mac

I have a special situation where I changed the e-mail address of my Apple ID from `erik.zivkovic@example.com` to `erik@example.com`.

After a few years I now need to pass on my computer to a colleague because I am getting a new one.

The problem is, I wiped the computer clean and handed it to my colleague, but "Find My" is still attached to my old computer and my colleague can't sign in completely.

When he's about to sign in using Apple ID the computer says:

```
Title: Apple ID Password

Enter Apple ID password for "erik.zivkovic@example.com" to turn off Find My Mac.
```

That's my old Apple ID e-mail address!

But neither my old nor my new Apple ID passwords work to get past that screen.

What can I do to unstick "Find My" from the old computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long (and helpful) chat with Apple support I was finally able to release my old computer from the grip of "Find My":

1. Make sure the problematic computer is connected to the internet
2. Sign in to iCloud.com using your Apple ID
3. In the map view, there is a dropdown where you can select computers
4. Select the problematic mac
5. Select "Erase Mac"
6. The mac should start erasing remotely
7. It should now be possible to "Remove from account" — do that
8. After erasing is complete

   - Use Disk Utility to create a new partition, APFS worked well for me — call the new partition "Macintosh HD"
   - Quit Disk Utility, then install macOS

Your old computer should now be disconnected from "Find My" and you can do a clean install using internet recovery.

I wrote (a more lengthy) [blog post](https://zkc.se/blog/unsticking-find-my-from-a-mac/) about it too